# How to create a API that return a boolean in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I need to create an API that returns a boolean in typescript, and I don't have a clear idea how to implement it , please give mea hand with this.
so my backend function is :

```
/**
 * @param appIdToSearch .
 * @param userAuthenticated .
 * @return Boolean
 */
@GetMapping(value = "/api/catalog/{appIdToSearch}/review/verify_user_have_review", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> verifyUserHaveReviewToApp(@PathVariable Integer appIdToSearch, Authentication userAuthenticated)
{
    try
    {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(appReviewService.verifyUserHaveReviewToApp(appIdToSearch, userAuthenticated));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.warn("[verifyUserHaveReviewToApp] [STATUS] - ERROR ");
        logger.warn("[verifyUserHaveReviewToApp] [EXCEPTION] " + e.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
    }
}
```

and now I need to call this in my frontend

And I have done something like this

```
  verifyUserHaveReviewToApp(appIdToSearch: number | string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get<boolean>(this.userHaveReviewToAppUrl.replace(':appIdToSearch:', String(appIdToSearch)))
      .pipe(
        map((res) => {
          return res;
        }),
      );
  }

userHaveReviewToAppUrl = '/api/catalog/:appIdToSearch:/review/verify_user_have_review';
```

but isn't not working, and I am not getting any error, but my API in backend isn't called cause I am debugging, can anyone give me hand, please?

Comment: Is the API not getting called or is the API not listening/accepting calls? What exactly do you expect to happen, what is not working?

Comment: Are you sure that backend code is Typescript at all? The naming convention smells like Java tbh.

Comment: how do you call `verifyUserHaveReviewToApp`? Do you have a `subscribe` call on that func?

Comment: the backend is in Java, the frontend is in typescript, the API in backend seems isn't being called, what I expected from is to return true or false, this call is a check if exists or not

Comment: Your question is how to create an API, but perhaps you mean how to CALL the API from the front-end?

Comment: If it isn't being called (= no connection attempt is visible in the network connections debug tab in your browser), it's probably that the function is never called. Set a breakpoint on it and check if it's called when you expect it to.

Comment: It doesn't go at the line of the response at all `return res;` maybe doesn't need the pipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to subscribe to your Observable. Unless you have a subscriber, the code will be not executed.

```
youServiceName.verifyUserHaveReviewToApp().subscribe()
```

Comment: Would be cool if you share what was exactly the issue you had.